# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API HTTP error 500 in production

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-500

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API and it has worked so far. I had to modify the CORS setting in Start.cs and after that it gives HTTP 500 error in production IIS.
It works correctly when I run it in the Visual Studio even though if I run it on the server with double clicks.
Unfortunattelly IIS log doesn't contain any information about error.
I have no idea why this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I over copied web.config and I forgot to overwrite modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" to modules="AspNetCoreModule".
Sorry.